# pip3 package installation fails with *ReadTimeoutError* regardless of default-timeout setting

Tags: python-3.x, pip, connection-pooling, ubuntu-20.04, connection-timeout

### The problem

**On a fresh and minimal Ubuntu 20.04 installation with** `ufw` **inactive:**

`pip3` fails with HTTPSConnectionPool timeout.

`pip3` fails to install or update **any** package in a freshly installed OS.

`pip3` fails with the same error when installing **local wheel files**.

`pip3` fails in **both** a virtual python environment **and** at the system-level environment.

### Environment

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
  fresh install,
  **apt** updated/upgraded
- Python 3.8

### Additional details

--default-timeout=100
[image]

--default-timeout=1000
[image]

#### UPDATE:

Traceback after user-interrupt `python -m pip install -U pip`

```
^CERROR: Operation cancelled by user
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 26, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 75, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 114, in main
    return self._main(args)
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 226, in _main
    self.handle_pip_version_check(options)
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 158, in handle_pip_version_check
    pip_self_version_check(session, options)
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/self_outdated_check.py", line 207, in pip_self_version_check
    best_candidate = finder.find_best_candidate("pip").best_candidate
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 883, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 827, in find_all_candidates
    package_links = self.process_project_url(
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 792, in process_project_url
    html_page = self._link_collector.fetch_page(project_url)
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 612, in fetch_page
    return _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 451, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 149, in _get_html_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 421, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 53, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py", line 352, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/home/zippy/Documents/python_workspace/py_virt_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

#### UPDATE

Sanity check - OK

```
laptop082:468$ curl https://pypi.org:443/simple/pip/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="pypi:repository-version" content="1.0">
    <title>Links for pip</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Links for pip</h1>
    <a href="https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/9d/1e313763bdfb6a48977b65829c6ce2a43eaae29ea2f907c8bbef024a7219/pip-0.2.tar.gz#sha256=88bb8d029e1bf4acd0e04d300104b7440086f94cc1ce1c5c3c31e3293aee1f81">pip-0.2.tar.gz</a><br/>
.
.
.
```

### Questions

What are my options?

Will a Ubuntu re-install be necessary?

#### UPDATE:

Re-installation of Ubuntu 20.04 did not resolve the problem.

Please advise.

Comment: can you tell the pip3 version?

Comment: pip3 version 20.1.1

Comment: You need to install ca-certificates package on ubuntu or update it if its outdated version

Comment: Try to update pip with `python -m pip install -U pip`, check your internet connection (maybe you have some static ip set with the wrong gateway?)

Comment: This also fails with the same error. My internet is purring along @ 150Mbs & I have no static IPs.

Comment: Please see update above.

Comment: `apt-get install ca-certificates` to install the package as suggested by @BijayRegmi. You can also try with `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y`. If it doesn't work, try reinstall pip `apt-get purge python3-pip &&  apt-get autoremove && apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: Performed these steps successfully.
Still getting the same error.

Comment: Dumb question but have you set your date and time correctly?

Comment: Date and time set correctly. Your question intrigues me @Bijay, what is your reasoning? Should I re-install Ubuntu w/out internet?

Comment: This looks like ssl handshake error to me and if date and time was not set correctly, your connection client might deny server certificate. Thats all I could think of. Why dont you reinstall pip as suggested above. And try `pip3` instead of `pip` if you have python2.7 installed in machine too.

Comment: I was successful calling `curl` (see above), wouldn't an ssl handshake error cause this to fail as well?